# <%= link_to 'Message me!', conversations_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: user.id), method: 'post'%> not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, message

i'm new to rails and trying this for too long. I'm following tutorial to create simple chat feature for rails https://medium.com/@carly_l/how-to-build-a-simple-chat-messaging-system-in-rails-2958efcea047 , and I whenever I click new message it's not routing properly.

**conversations.index.html.erb**

```
 <h3>Mailbox</h3>


  <% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
  
    <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id || conversation.recipient_id == current_user.id %>

      <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id %>
        <% recipient = User.find(conversation.recipient_id) %>
      <% else %>
        <% recipient = User.find(conversation.sender_id) %>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to recipient.first_name, conversation_messages_path(conversation)%>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

#### All Users

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <% if user.id != current_user.id %>
  <div class="item">
    <%= user.first_name %> <%= link_to 'Message me!', conversations_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: user.id), method: 'post'%>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**conversations index **

```
  @users = User.all
@conversations = Conversation.all
```

**conversations create function**

```
def create
byebug
@user = current_user
if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],params[:recipient_id]).present?
  @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).first
else
  @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
end
redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
end
```

**routes.rb **

```
  resources :conversations do
     resources :messages
  end
```

when I click message me path is

```
http://localhost:3000/conversations?recipient_id=1&sender_id=6
```

and does nothing.

Comment: What rails version does your app use? Did you see some requests in browser console or app logs?

Comment: `method: :post` only works with the old Rails Unobtrusive Javascript driver that was the default in Rails 6 and earlier. In Rails 7 with Turbo the equivilent is `<%= link_to ..., "data-turbo-method" => 'post'%>`.

Comment: You can also use `button_to`  instead of `link_to` which works with without any javascript trickery.

Comment: On a side note its a pretty dismal tutorial IMHO. It would be way better to use a user_conversations join table instead of the whole `conversation.sender_id/recipient_id` oxymoron (its not much of a conversation if only one party is talking).

Comment: I'm using rails 7 
i tried this <%= link_to ..., "data-turbo-method" => 'post'%> as well @max. but it seems to pass an other error ,   
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: conversation):  
thanks for help i'll try the other way with creating join table you suggested.